# SQL Report Builder Column Group Merge Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a basic report with a one Dataset and one column group.
When I run the report, the column groups shows all the columns I want to see as expected.  However, some of the columns, I need to be merged.

For example, I have these columns that all show up, but need to merge to a single column Visa, then report shows the transaction amounts.
Visa Sign, Visa PIN, Visa Tap

How would I merge these columns and rename the main column to just Visa?

My first approach was the modify the dataset query and change anything the payment type to "Visa", but it turns out I can't use update statements since the raw data is still needed for another report.

Next, I tried using Lookups to find anything with "Visa%" and display the the data, but I still can't get the other columns merged to 1.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Hi, please describe data types in that three columns.

Comment: You could use a CASE expression (in another query/view/SP) like this: `CASE WHEN YourColumn LIKE 'Visa%' THEN 'Visa' ELSE YourColumn END AS NewColumn`

Comment: Datatypes are just text descriptions. I will try a case statement and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: The CASE statement worked! Can you add this as the answer please?  Thanks!